# Junk Characters in email generated from Oracle report server on ORACLE 12c OFM

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Oracle report server has generated report in pdf format and same is attached in email. Body of the email contains junk characters(unreadable format) although pdf generated in perfectly fine.

We are migrating from Oracle db 11g to 12c and Oracle OFM 11g to 12c. Reports and email send on 11g environment is perfectly fine. We have intially used AL32UTF 8 and NLS Characterset on report server but encountered this problem. This is resolved when we have changed NLS characterset to WE8ISO8859P1 but then Euro symbol was not appearing and getting inverted question mark.

After this we have changed to WE8ISO8859P15 this resolves euro symbol issue but now we are facing agin the junk character issue in EMAIL body.

Email is generated from report server using mail reply server.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: How do you create and send the mail?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the procedure

Comment: this code is working fine in 11g and even in 12c it is attaching the pdf report but only in the body of email we are getting junk characters.